# show complete address instead of longitude and latitude

Tags: android, gps

I am working on GPS location whereby i get the longitude and latitude but i dont know how to get the complete address instead of this. i have followed a tutorial for my code and saw many posts to find out how can i get the address based on this but coudnt find any probable solution

Following is my code:

GpsTracker.java

```
package com.example.gpslocator;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

     private final Context mContext;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location location; // location
        double latitude; // latitude
        double longitude; // longitude

        // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

        // Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GpsTracker(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }


        public Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;


        }

        public void stopUsingGPS(){
            if(locationManager != null){
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GpsTracker.this);
            }       
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         * @return boolean
         * */
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
         * */
        public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gpslocator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;
     TextView textview;

    // GPSTracker class
    GpsTracker gps;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         GpsTracker gpsTracker = new GpsTracker(this);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                    // create class object
                    gps = new GpsTracker(MainActivity.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled     
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        // \n is for new line
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                    }else{
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }

                }
            });
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the received location and feed it to the GeoCoder or the Geocoding API.

- The [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) is part of the SDK since API Level 1 and results in an ArrayList of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) Objects.
- [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en) is a web-service, which responses a JSON.

Both solutions are delivering detailed information and can be used for geocoding (location to address) or reverse geocoding (address to location).

Edit:

Use the GeoCoder like this:

```
if(GeoCoder.isPresent()) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            // do something with your address
        } else {
            // No results for your location
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know how to implement that

Comment: In which class i have to add this?

Comment: @hinafatima Add it as a function in your MainActivity.

Comment: the address only shows street not the complete address.. like it show 163rd st .

Comment: @hinafatima Have a look at the method getAddressLine() of the Address class. If you use the Address.toString() you will see all the information which the Object contains. Extract that one you need.